# Is there a simple way to attribute a CC image on flickr?

Tags: images, flickr, copyright, copy-paste

To legally reuse a CC image from Flickr, you must attribute properly the source and license, as explained on this blog: http://librarianbyday.net/2009/09/28/how-to-attribute-a-creative-commons-photo-from-flickr/ Another question about how to properly attribute was answered https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/47595/19350

Proper attribution involves many steps of linking info back to the source. The relative complexity of attribution seems to dissuade people from properly doing this (they will tend to just copy/paste the image and be done with it).

Is there a tool or place on Flickr where I can copy/paste the attribution to a CC image such that I can simplify this process? I'm looking for a "Copy image with attribution" feature, that when you then paste, supplies all the information in various formats.

Note that when I copy text from my Kindle reader on PC, the text will be pasted with a reference to the book and location (relative within). It's a "smart" copy/paste that sort-of does what I'm asking. Here's an example (I just selected a paragraph in the Kindle, did a copy, then pasted it here. The second part contains the attribution to the book.):

> Applying the Language
>
> To apply the patterns in this book to the solution of the example problem, first build a working pattern language for the project. The language will contain those elements of the fault tolerant vocabulary presented here that will be useful in the design of the system. Patterns are not included if they will clearly not be needed or useful.
>
> Hanmer, Robert (2013-07-12). Patterns for Fault Tolerant Software (Wiley Software Patterns Series) (Kindle Locations 4972-4975). Wiley. Kindle Edition.

I'm looking for something similar, but with CC images on Flickr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Imagecodr.org](http://imagecodr.org) is mentioned in the OP's link to [librarianbyday](http://librarianbyday.net/2009/09/28/how-to-attribute-a-creative-commons-photo-from-flickr/). Put a flickr URL and you get the following (it's possible to vary the format):

```
<div about='http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2639/3979663993_90d928ba13_m.jpg'>
<a href='http://www.flickr.com/photos/umpcportal/3979663993/' target='_blank'>
<img xmlns:dct='http://purl.org/dc/terms/' href='http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage' rel='dct:type' src='http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2639/3979663993_90d928ba13_m.jpg' alt='three device mobility by umpcportal.com, on Flickr' title='three device mobility by umpcportal.com, on Flickr' border='0'/></a><br/>
<a rel='license' href='http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.0/' target='_blank'>
<img src='http://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-nd/2.0/80x15.png' alt='Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-No Derivative Works 2.0 Generic License' title='Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-No Derivative Works 2.0 Generic License' border='0' align='left'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;by&nbsp;
<a href='http://www.flickr.com/people/umpcportal/' target='_blank'>&nbsp;</a>
<a xmlns:cc='http://creativecommons.org/ns#' rel='cc:attributionURL' property='cc:attributionName' href='http://www.flickr.com/people/umpcportal/' target='_blank'>umpcportal.com</a><a href='http://www.imagecodr.org/' target='_blank'>&nbsp;</a></div>
```

which looks something like

[image: three device mobility by umpcportal.com, on Flickr]

Note that the name of the work displays when you hover over the image -- perhaps not the best solution. We don't see the Author's name (Steve Paine) in the metadata, although the link to umpcportal may be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Photopin.com, which indexes photos from flickr.com, supports partially this feature. It is still not entirely compliant with the CC attribution requirements mentioned in the question.

On Photopin, once you find an image, you hover over it and click "get photo" which brings up a dialog as such:

[image: photopin dialog]

The last part "Grab HTML for Attribution" is a step in the right direction. However, **it still doesn't "credit the author or include the title of the Work" (which are parts of a proper attribution)**.

> photo credit: [umpcportal.com](http://www.flickr.com/photos/umpcportal/3979663993/) via [photopin](http://photopin.com) [cc](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.0/)

In the example above, there should also be the name of the author (Steve Paine) and the title ("three device mobility"); all these data are available on the flickr page at http://www.flickr.com/photos/umpcportal/3979663993/